# Internal matchmaking service (for social movements, etc.)

Tags: social-networks

I'm currently working on building the EA movement ([effective altruism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_altruism)). It's struck me that a major constraint of any social movement is linking the resources of people within the movement.

Is there any sort of matchmaking service that asks each member of a movement or organization to enter in data about their interests, skills, and needs, and then automatically suggests other folks they should talk to?

Answer (score 2):

Seeing general recommendations would be great, but it's worth pointing to two related websites that enable something like this in the effective altruist movement:

http://skillshare.im/ - lets EAs offer and request goods and services from one another, to help each other out

http://eaprofiles.com/ - EA Profiles, which let people share their interests, skills, and needs and contact one another, facilitating what you describe